# What is the parameter type of a function that works read-only on a range?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

With *ranges* from C++20 I have a function that works on a range, **read only**. If it was a `string` I would have the parameter be a `string_view`. But what about a range of `int`s?

I saw `std::ranges::input_range` and that works quite well:

```
void printBinary(std::ranges::input_range auto&& range)
{
    for(const auto &elem : range) {
        std::bitset<4> x(elem);
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
}
```

As far as I understood **ranges** are for "read/write" and **views** are for "read-only". So I find it strange that I use a **range** for a read-only parameter. It does the job, mind you, because if I remove the `const` in the loop and add `x = 0;` inside it I get an error -- so why is this called a "range" and not a "view"?

Second, I don't understand why I use `&&` for the parameter. I know it's not an RValue but a "Forwarding/Universal Reference", but I probably didn't not grasp all the implications here. It just looks strange in comparision with just `string_view` as parameter type.

Note: I know the code above can be written as a pipeline. But I want to understand about ranges and views here.

So my question is: What is the best parameter type for a function that works read-only on a range of `int`s.

Comment: The requirement for being a range is only that it has [begin() and end()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range). It says nothing about readable or writeable.

Comment: `std::ranges::input_range` can be modified [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/coMP3836Y). A `const` range cannot be modified though.

Comment: Use `input_range` for read access, and `output_range` for write access. Views have nothing to do with read-only. (Some views are, but others are not.)

Comment: @Jarod42 "auto&& is not r-value, ", yes that's what I said, I know it isn't . "Forwarding Reference" or "Universal Reference", I should have mentioned the name. I Edit it.

Comment: @BoP "has begin() and end()"? You mean that it supports "begin(...)" and "end(...)", or it would not in C-Arrays and such, yes? But I did think I read somewhere that the _idea_ behind the differences between "Ranges" versus "Views" was the read/write-ability. I think I need to find a good introduction into Ranges/Views. I found the talks of "Tristan Brindle", and they were good, but did not convey the ideas well.

Answer (score 4):

> As far as I understood ranges are for "read/write" and views are for "read-only".

This is incorrect. The more roughly correct split is that a range is just anything you can iterate over at all, and a view is a range that doesn't own its elements (which itself isn't even entirely correct, since views can be owning, but the difference between range and view has always been sort of fuzzy given that you can iterate a range). Importantly though, there is nothing inherently "read-only" about a view.

For instance:

```cpp
struct Point { int x, y; };
std::vector<Point> points = { ... };
auto xs = points | std::views::transform(&Point::x);
```

`points` and `xs` are both ranges, `xs` is a view while `points` is not. But `xs` is definitely a mutable range, you can do something like:

```cpp
for (int& x : xs) { ++x; }
```

And that will increment all the x-coordinates in `points`.

---

Next, the reason that range algorithms are written like this:

```cpp
void print(std::ranges::input_range auto&& range)
```

rather than this:

```cpp
void print(std::ranges::input_range const& range)
```

is two fold. First, views don't propagate `const`, so you're not getting the read-only you might want anyway (a `span<int> const` is still a range of `int&`, not a range of `int const&` - for that you need a `span<int const>`). Second, some views are not const-iterable (e.g. filter, drop, most input ranges), so taking by `const&` might mean you don't even have a range.

---

So if `const&` isn't the way to get read-only, how do we do it? Well, in C++23 there's an adaptor for that:

```cpp
template <std::ranges::range R> 
void print(R&& r) {
    auto read_only = std::forward<R>(r) | std::views::as_const;
    // use read_only here
}
```

`read_only` is going to be a read-only view onto `r` (which, if `r` is already a constant range, might just be a view onto `r` itself). If you want further protection, to avoid accidentally using `r`, then you can make this an overload set:

```cpp
template <std::ranges::range R> 
    requires std::ranges::constant_range<R>
void print(R&& r) {
    // read-only
}


template <std::ranges::range R> 
void print(R&& r) {
    return print(std::forward<R>(r) | std::views::as_const);
}
```

The first overload will be a better match for those ranges that are already constant. For those that aren't, the second will call the first. Note that you don't *just* want to provide the first overload, since you want do be able to pass a `vector<int>` to `print` - that isn't a constant range, so the first overload will reject it - but you can make it one, which is what the second overload is for.

In C++20, you can implement this view yourself, though [it's complicated](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2278r4.html). For more, see [coercing deep const-ness](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2021/09/10/deep-const/).

Comment: *"views can be owning"* Which ones? Do you consider generator as `iota` view?

Comment: @Jarod42 `iota` is a view, yes. Whether it's "owning" or not is a matter of interpretation. But `ranges::owning_view(std::vector{1, 2, 3})` is a view that definitely owns its data.

Comment: `std::generator<T>` is the more interesting example since it can own arbitrary amounts of data. Or none.